# JQuery File Upload with Spring MVC: web page does not react to anything

Tags: jquery, css, spring, ant, upload

I am trying to design a simple file upload web with JQuery File Upload and Spring MVC following this tutorial: http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-jquery-file-upload-multiple-dragdrop-progress/. The problem that I have is that the webpage does not have the supposed behavior, it does not show my CSS and it does not update the list with files to be uploaded after add some of them using the form. The only difference with the example is that I am using Ant, not Maven, and I don't know if maybe I am missing some important files related with Ant. I attach my index.jsp. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time!

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
<script src="/js/jquery.1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap just to have good looking page -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- we code these -->
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/dropzone.css"      type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/myuploadfunction.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Spring MVC - jQuery File Upload</h1>
<div style="width:500px;padding:20px">

    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/upload.html" multiple>

    <div id="dropzone">Drop files here</div>

    <div id="progress">
        <div style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>

    <table id="uploaded-files">
        <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>File Size</th>
            <th>File Type</th>
            <th>Download</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: so still your css is not getting load???

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dev. The css is loaded but it does not attach a file to be uploaded when I drop it to the dropzone. The plugin for the Upload still does not list the selected files..

Comment: first of all are you able to upload file using `<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/upload.html" multiple>` input box???

Comment: I can use the form to select the files, but they are not uploaded because they are not listed as in the example (jQuery plugin does not react)

Comment: please refer this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784465/upload-a-file-from-client-side-to-server-side-with-ajax/29788715#29788715